# image id passing in find selector jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, src

[image: this is working snippet]I have to pass some value in find() selector dynamically to change the image so I am trying to pass like below.

```
 $('.vd-accordion-grid .collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
            var imageid=$(this).parent().find("img").attr("id");
            var crid='img#'+imageid;
        alert("image id :::   "+imageid);
        alert("crid::   "+crid);
           $(this).parent().find(crid).attr("src", "resources/vidal/images/accordion_down.svg");
        }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
           $(this).parent().find(crid).attr("src", "resources/vidal/images/accordion_right.svg");
       });
```

but image is not changing, but when i am hard coding id of image in find then image is successfully changing.

```
 $(this).parent().find('img#picid0').attr("src", "resources/vidal/images/accordion_down.svg");
```

Actually i have written html code in java custome tags please find below.

```
"<a data-toggle=\"collapse\" href=\"#collapse"+iClauseCnt+"\" aria-expanded=\"true\" aria-controls=\"collapse"+iClauseCnt+"\" class=\"\" style=\"color:white;font-size: 15px;\">");
                         "<img id=\"picid"+iClauseCnt+"\" src=\""+webcontext+"/resources/vidal/images/accordion_down.svg\" alt=\"accordion_down\">");
                         ""+eleClause.valueOf("@name"));
                         "</a>");
```

Comment: can you add working snippet :)

Comment: what do tou get in `crid`(do you get `img#picid0` for example??) ?

Comment: i was just checking only both are same i think rather directly passing there i am passing through var.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is good to go, just a small thing to consider
in the on('hidden.bs.collapse') callback function, the variable crid is "undefined" because it was not declared in the scope of this function

check code below

```
 $('.vd-accordion-grid .collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
        var imageid=$(this).parent().find("img").attr("id");
        var crid='img#'+imageid;
    alert("image id :::   "+imageid);
    alert("crid::   "+crid);
       $(this).parent().find(crid).attr("src", "resources/vidal/images/accordion_down.svg");
    }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
       // crid here was undefined <======================
       var imageid=$(this).parent().find("img").attr("id");
       var crid='img#'+imageid;
       $(this).parent().find(crid).attr("src", "resources/vidal/images/accordion_right.svg");
   });
```

let me know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

> you code is right, I think, you are not image-id correctly. please
>   check it out.

Please add like this:

```
$(this).parent().find('img#'+imageid).attr("src", "resources/vidal/images/accordion_down.svg");
```